# passing session data from controller to view laravel Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, arrays, session, object, laravel-5.4

My code is having an error. I am passing a data from my controller to view. I tried to `print_r` the data so that I can see the structure of the data.

Here is my controller:

```
public function getAllCart() 
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('mycartview');
    }
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    print_r($cart);
    return view('mycartview', ['products' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);
}
```

my view:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge"></span>
        <strong>{{ $product['item']['title'] }}</strong>
        <span class="label label-success">{{ $product['price'] }}</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Reduce by 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Remove all</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Here is the result of print_r:

```
App\Cart Object ( [items] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [qty] => 2 [price] => 30000 [item] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 2 [subcategory_id] => 2 [price] => 15000 [quantity] => 5 [status] => published [created_at] => 2017-08-23 05:41:02 [updated_at] => 2017-08-23 05:41:02 ) ) ) [totalQty] => 1 [totalPrice] => 15000 )
```

Comment: There is no `title` in the **object** `item` if there was you could perhaps access it like `{{ $product['item']->title }}`

Comment: lol wow thanks it was $product['item']->title. i forgot to pass the title but it works $product['item']->title thanks

Comment: np, glad to help